# session_start() is causing an object to become non-object

Tags: php, session, object

I have this class that have a function to load other classes and create instances.

if you used this class like this:

```
    $test = new test();
   $test->load("email");
```

it works perfectly as expected
but when using session_start();

```
$test = new test();
session_start();
$test->load("email");
```

an error is created and nothing else is there: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object in bla bla bla

the class used with session_start:

```
<?php

 class test
{


 function load($class){

  static $objects = array();

  if (isset($objects[$class]))
  {
   return $objects[$class];
  }

  require('libraries/'.$class.'.php');

  $name = 'ext_'.$class;

  $objects[$class] =& new $name();

  $this->$class = $objects[$class];

  return $objects[$class];


 }

}


$test = new test();

session_start();

$test->load("email");
?>
```

and here is libraries/email.php:

```
<?php


class ext_email
{

 function ext_email(){
         echo "email is working";
 }

}

?>
```

can you please advice what is wrong with this? a way to improve the load function?
this thing works on some installations of apache and fail to work on others. depending on some configs that I don't know what exactly is it..

I want to be able to do the following:
    $test = new test();

```
session_start();

$test->load("email");
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Interesting, as a walkaround, couldn't you just stick the `session_start` call at the absolute top of your code?

Comment: Works fine on my end. Perhaps you should try a `var_dump` on `$test` before and after the call to `session_start()` to see what's changing.

Comment: no I can't move session_start(), also it's always the same even if I moved session_start to the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have some variable named `test` in `$_SESSION`, and have [`register_globals`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) enabled ?

In which case, the `$_SESSION['test']` variable will be created as a global `$test` variable by the call to `session_start()`, overridding any existing `$test` variable of your script.

This would also explain why this is happening on some servers and not some others : `register_globals` is `Off` by default -- and has been for many years, but some hosts keep it enabled :-(

*(When people say `register_globals` is evil, it's not without a good reason...)*

For more informations, you can read the [Using Register Globals][2] page of the manual -- there is even a paragraph about `$_SESSION` and some problems that `register_globals` can cause.

Now, on how to fix this... Well, I suppose the fastest way would be to make sure that `session_start()` is called before you set `$test` to what you want it to be :

```
session_start();
$test = new test();
$test->load("email");
```

This way, even if a `$test` is created because of `register_globals`, your variable will override it -- and the last one is the one that's right ^^

But the best solution would be to turn `register_globals` Off : that's a reliquate from the past... That should probably never have existed :-(

*(There are some bad things in PHP ; that's one of them, in my opinion)*

Comment: Cool! thanks a lot that solved my problem I changed test in $_SESSION and it work now!!

Comment: I guess that's a solution too -- but don't forget you might run into the same kind of trouble again, for other variables !;;;  YOu're welcome :-)

Comment: yes you are right, but it's not possible to ask everybody to disable register_globals for this to work !!! thanks again

Comment: Make it possible or wait for this house of cards to come crashing down